# Can I filter out onNotificationPosted() duplicates in Marshmallow?

Tags: android, notifications

I have a notification listener set up. I have a function that's called every time a notification is posted. On Lollipop, it works great. The function fires once per new notification. This is what I want. I want to (let's say) log my incoming notifications, one at a time.

On Marshmallow, the behavior is different. Consider SMS notifications.
If I get an SMS from Person X, onNotificationPosted() is triggered once, and I log something like "You have a text from Person X..."

If that notification isn't cleared by the user, and an additional SMS is received from Person Y, onNotificationPosted() is triggered 3 times. One of these describes the cluster, like "You have 2 texts," another is "You have a text from Person Y," and the third is "You have a text from Person X."

So from receiving 2 texts, onNotificationPosted() is fired 4 times, and 2 of these are practically identical. This becomes a lot worse when there are multiple unread messages from multiple people. They're all reported all over again when a new one comes in.

Is there some way for me to filter out the duplicates just by looking at the StatusBarNotification object?

I see that, in the case of SMS, I can look for groupKey != null and sortKey == 00 in the notification properties to make sure I'm only reporting the most recent (new data) SMS, but I'm worried that different apps will have different sorting schemes, rendering this approach invalid.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hey have you found solution for this ?

Comment: Hey have you found solution for this ?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problem and turns out, there's no direct solution to it. You have to implement your own logic to identify duplicates. I recommend you to create your own notification class, extract the information needed from the StatusBarNotification you get in onNotificationPosted() method and initialize the custom notification. Then you can create your own equals method to determine duplicates.